# Auto redirecting to Salesforce Classic Home page

Tags: lightning-web-components, chrome

I have a Lightning App Page and I placing the LWC component in that page. As soon as I click on F12 to debug the LWC component, after few seconds the browser is redirecting automatically to salesforce classic. This redirection is happening only if open the dev tools.
Any reason?

Comment: Are you attempting to preview the page in a different form factor (like mobile)? If so this is known behaviour, like [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344931/when-i-hit-f12-in-lightning-exp-salesforce-switches-to-salesforce-classic)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We need to Toggle the Device Toolbar.